# How to communicate multiples component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am learning `React Js`, but i will know communicate multiples component with this library. For example:

#### file1.jsx

```
class fileOne extends Component{
   //get some value
   //do something
   //send value to file2
}
```

#### file2.jsx

```
class fileTwo extends Component{
   //recive some value
   //do something
   //and return some value
   //to file1
}
```

#### file3.jsx

```
class fileThree extends Component{
   //recive some value
   //do something
   //and return some value
   //to file1
}
```

Don't matter if this file are in the same folder.

Comment: I recommend you read through the official [Quick Start guides](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html) before anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File one contains our state, we can pass this state down to any component by passing it down as a prop.

I pass this.state.greeting which contains 'hello' as a prop named greeting to the fileTwo component.

Also you want class names to start with capital letters.

```
class FileOne extends Component{
state={greeting:'hello'}

render() {
 return (
 <div> 
    <FileTwo greeting={this.state.greeting}/> 
    <FileThree greeting={this.state.greeting} />
 </div> 
  )
 }
}
```

FileTwo can acess greeting from fileOne by using `this.props`. We can render it by using curly braces.

```
class FileTwo extends Component{
 render() {
  return (
    <div>This is the greeting {this.props.greeting} </div>
   )
  }
}
```

Functional stateless component can recieve props from the parent component FileOne.

```
const FileThree = (props) => <div> 
    This is the third file component, 
    it can recieve props just like the second file {props.greeting} 
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but, i see that the principal component get all the `state` that are share between this and other's?

Comment: yeah so fileone will be your toplevel and any component within fileOne's render method can recieve the state.

Comment: Thanks, in this case, is not necessary use the `props` into the `constructor`, like `super(props)`?

Comment: no you only need super props if you are trying to acess this.props.greeting inside the constructor.

Comment: sorry, why you don't use `this` in the 3 option?

Comment: you do not need a refrence to this in a functional stateless component you can just use props.whateverpropyouwant