# How to call/execute method/function from another component react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I will want to know, if is possible call or execute a method or function from another component.

I would like to run asynchronously the function that is the **tableInformacion.js**, which has a request `get`, but after the call of the`post` request is made that I have in **address.js**.

#### address.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import request from 'superagent';
import {getSolarDayInformation} from './tableInformation.js';

import '../styles/main.css';

class AddressInput extends Component{

    constructor(){    
        super();
        this.state = {
            address: "",
            api:"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=",
            direccion: "",
            latitud: "",
            longitud:""          
        };
    } 

    render(){
        return(
            <div> 

                <form>      

                    <input type="text" 
                           value={this.state.address} 
                           onChange={this.updateAdress.bind(this)}
                           placeholder="Escriba la direccion"/>

                    <button onClick={this.getAddressGeo.bind(this)}>Consultar</button> 
                </form>

                <ul className="None-Style">
                    <li><label>Direccion:</label>{this.state.direccion}</li>
                    <li><label>Latitud:{this.state.latitud}</label></li>
                    <li><label>Longitud:{this.state.longitud}</label></li>
                </ul>
            </div> 
        )
    }

    updateAdress(event){
        this.setState({
            address: event.target.value
        });
    }

    getAddressGeo(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        const apiUrl = this.state.api + this.state.address;

        request.post(apiUrl).then((res) => {

            const direccionCompleta = res.body.results[0].formatted_address; 
            const Latitud = res.body.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
            const Longitud = res.body.results[0].geometry.location.lng;             

           this.setState({
                direccion: direccionCompleta,
                latitud: Latitud, 
                longitud: Longitud
            })

        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.message);
        });

        getSolarDayInformation();

    } 
}

export default AddressInput;
```

#### tableInformacion.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import request from 'superagent';

class TableConsumeInformation extends Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            apiSolarInformation: 'https://asdc-arcgis.larc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/power/v1beta/DataAccess.py?request=',
            parameters:'execute&identifier=SinglePoint&parameters=ALLSKY_SFC_SW_DWN&',
            startDate:'0101&',
            endDate:'1231&',
            comunity: 'userCommunity=SSE&tempAverage=DAILY&outputList=JSON,ASCII&',
            latitudePlace:'lat=',
            longitudePlace:'&lon=',
            anonymous:'&user=anonymous'
        };
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h2>Information Energy</h2>
                <table></table>
            </div>
        );
    }

    getSolarDayInformation(){
        apiSolarUrl = 'https://asdc-arcgis.larc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/power/v1beta/DataAccess.py?request=execute&identifier=SinglePoint&parameters=ALLSKY_SFC_SW_DWN&startDate=20170101&endDate=20171231&userCommunity=SSE&tempAverage=DAILY&outputList=JSON,ASCII&lat=11.373&lon=-72.253&user=anonymous';
        request.get(apiSolarUrl).then((req, res) => {
            console.log(res.body);
        });
    }

}

export default TableConsumeInformation;
```

Comment: What I understand from your question you want to pass some data from `tableInformacion.js` to `address.js`. you can do this using `props` follow this link https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/props.html

Comment: No, just execute the function/method `getSolarDayInformation()`, let me edit the question

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about the getSolarDayInformation function in this case.

In your case here, it looks like the easiest thing to do would be to refactor your function into its own file and import it into all the places its needed. There is no reason for it to be a object method as it has no dependency on the object state.

Comment: that is, create a js file that contains that function only, and then make the call?

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a **helper functions file**, something like

`helper.js`

```
export const getSolarDayInformation = () => {
    ...
}
```

Then, **import** the method in your other file(s)

```
import {getSolarDayInformation} from 'path/to/your/file';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, excuse me, you have time in this moment for some questions?

Comment: Not too much, but I have about 20 min

Comment: for example, i do this question, [communication between components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49373223/how-to-comunicate-multiples-component), but the answer is not i want it, i want to export some value, for example, the `chid 2` to `parent`, and this value, send to `child 3`

Comment: You can have a parent component, and declare the methods on the parent. Then, from the childs, you can call the functions in the parent, using callback functions, update the state, and then pass new updated data to the childs.
You should look into React docs for props and state:
https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: Thanks again, i'm not speak english, but i learning, i'm seeing that its necesary

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales, intenta con un tutorial básico, como este: https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/primeros-pasos-con-react/

Comment: Hablas español, menos mal, vi tu nombre y no perdí la esperanza. Gracias, espero poder solventar con eso que em pasaste y esto, que encontré, https://github.com/jlobos/react-espanol